# Macbook Pro mid 2012 connect to projector via thunderbolt

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, hdmi

Maybe I need to duplicate this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1113663/thunderbolt-or-mini-display-port-connect-macbook-pro-mid-2012-to-a-3d-projector) here I am not sure. I need to connect my macbook pro to HDMI port on 3d projector to be able watch full hd or 3d video. What cable should I buy/use?

Comment: @Allan thanks for suggestion, yea I've read it, in any case I still have misunderstanding between thunderbolt and mini display port, and what can fit my requirements.

Comment: Check out this [link](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/228892/119271) or this [link](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205626/119271) for the differences on Thunderbolt and mDP

Comment: As written this question is a duplicate. If you don't understand the answer there, please update the question to indicate what you are not understanding.